# Format JSON from two flat structured array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, performance, data-structures

I need to make a nested JSON out of two flat structured arrays which are kind of linked together, I am able to get the first level but not able to nest it in javascript.

Below is the problem statement.

I have 2 arrays:

```
data = ["HSP - FS", "FS-M", "Lo Co", "GO A", "CQM","whatever"];

type = ["Epic","Sub - Epic","Sub - Epic","Epic","Sub - Epic","Story"];
```

the `type` array and `data` array are linked together and with type and description on the same index like

`type[0]` which is `data[0]`, so it will be "Epic: HSP-FS", but this does not end here, this Epic has child elements also which are Sub - Epics and their description is placed under the same array element, so `type[1]` which is "Sub-Epic" has its data in `data[1]` which is "FS-M" and so on till next "Epic" is found in the type array.

So JSON would be like

```
{0:{
        Epic: "HSP - FS",
        Sub-Epic:"FS-M",
        Sub-Epic:"Lo Co"
    },    
    1:{
        Epic: "GO A",
        Sub-Epic:"CQM",
        Story:"whatever"
    }}
```

Structure of array and JSON is fixed, and even array can have any number of Epics, Sub Epics or story but the order will be maintained as in all the child of Epics will be there until next occurrence of Epic happens.

Issue is I am not able to write loop to get the output..I have till now tried something like iterating and joining these two arrays

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: What issue are you having? What have you tried? What is your question?

Comment: Issue is I am not able to write loop to get the output..I have till now tried something like iterating and joining these two arrays..

Comment: Did you want JSON text or JavaScript objects?

Comment: My bad I am not that descriptive, I want JSON format as
{0:{
        Epic: "HSP - FS",
        Sub-Epic:"FS-M",
        Sub-Epic:"Lo Co"
    },    
    1:{
        Epic: "GO A",
        Sub-Epic:"CQM",
        Story:"whatever"
    }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have repeated named properties in a JSON object, but you can use arrays instead:

```
var array = [];

for(var i=0; i < data.length; ++i)
{
    var t = type[i];
    var d = data[i];


    if (t == "Epic")
    {
         array.push({ "Epic": d});
    }
    else
    {
         if(typeof(array[array.length-1][t]) == "undefined")
         {
             array[array.length-1][t] = [];
         }

         array[array.length-1][t].push(d)        
    }
}
```

This is the resulting JSON:

```
[{
    "Epic": "HSP - FS",
    "Sub - Epic": ["FS-M","Lo Co"]
 },    
 {
    "Epic": "GO A",
    "Sub - Epic": ["CQM"],
    "Story": ["whatever"]
 }]
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but first element does not have 2 sub epics, output should be something like:                                                           {0:{
            Epic: "HSP - FS",
            Sub-Epic:"FS-M",
            Sub-Epic:"Lo Co"
        },    
        1:{
            Epic: "GO A",
            Sub-Epic:"CQM",
            Story:"whatever"
        }}

Comment: Probably you need to push all the elements before next occurrence of "Epic".

Comment: Thank you so much @MarkCidade, this helps, sorry I can't vote up the answer, I do not have enough badges....:)

Comment: Just a wild thought, what happens if you have 3 arrays and then you need to link it the same way, say a sub-epic has a description to it and is on the same index level...

Comment: Then you would do something like with "Epic": `array[array.length-1]["Sub - Epic"].push({name: d, description : sourceArray[i]}) `